# Получить все отмеченные чекбоксы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно выбрать имена всех отмеченных чекбоксов,

скрипт:

```js
var nonno = $(".form-item-checkbox > input").map(function(indx, element) {
  return $(element).attr('name');
});
```

возвращает список всех имён.

следующий, по идее, должен выбрать все отмеченные.

```js
var nonno = $(".form-item-checkbox > input").prop("checked").map(function(indx, element) {
  return $(element).attr('name');
});
```

Но не работает.

Comment: prop возвращает значение для первого элемента. уберите prop и попробуйте input:checked в селекторе

Answer (score 1):

Можно массив из `checkbox` отфильтровать по наличию атрибута `checked`.

```js
var nonno = $(".form-item-checkbox > input")
  .filter(function(index, element) {
    return $(element).attr('checked') == 'checked';
  })
  .map(function(indx, element) {
    return $(element).attr('name');
  });

console.log(nonno);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="form-item-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" checked name="Check1" /> Check 1</li>
  <li class="form-item-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="Check2" /> NoCheck 1</li>
  <li class="form-item-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" checked name="Check3" /> Check 2</li>
  <li class="form-item-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" checked name="Check4" /> Check 3</li>
  <li class="form-item-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="Check5" /> NoCheck 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос: Вам нужно получить атрибут `name` у активных чекбоксов?

Вот решение:

```js
$('.form-item_checkbox input:checked').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
  // Output: input_1, input_3
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="form-item_checkbox">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="input_1" checked /> Input #1
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="input_2" /> Input #2
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="input_3" checked /> Input #3
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="input_4" /> Input #4
  </li>
</ul>
```

**UPD.** Если же Вам нужно при изменении чекбокса добавлять/удалять его имя из массива, то вот ещё одно решение:

```js
var listName = [];

Array.prototype.remove = function(value) {
  var idx = this.indexOf(value);
  if (idx != -1) {
    return this.splice(idx, 1);
  }
  return false;
}

$('.form-item_checkbox input').change(function(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    listName.push(e.target.name);
    console.log('PUSH NAME =>', listName);
  } else {
    listName.remove(e.target.name);
    console.log('REMOVE NAME =>', listName);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="form-item_checkbox">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="input_1" /> Input #1
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="input_2" /> Input #2
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="input_3" /> Input #3
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="input_4" /> Input #4
  </li>
</ul>
```